# in how long will he arrive

Tags: grammar

Those are correct:

How soon will he arrive?

When will he arrive?

Yesterday I said: In how long will he arrive? 
-- Is this wrong?

Also, I remember my Indian roommate used to say something like: At what time will he arrive?
-- Not nice English, right?

Thank you.

Comment: "How long will he be?" is often used (in this and other contexts), but "In how long will he arrive?" –  which might even be seen as being the more logical expression – is never used. "At what time will he arrive?" is used, but is more formal and less usual than "When will he arrive?"

Comment: There's nothing ungrammatical, illogical, or wrong about your sentence as such. It's just never used, for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

As other have said, "In how long will he arrive" is not used. Here are some alternatives that you might use instead:

> How long will he be?
>   How long until he gets here?
>   How long until he's here?
>
> At what time will he arrive?
>   What time will he get here?
>
> When will he get here?
>   When will he arrive?
>   When is he set to arrive?
>
> When should we expect him?

Answer (score 0):

We don't say Ïn how long will he arrive". I think that "At  what time will he arrive?" is correct English and is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another form that can be used from those suggested by LMS could be this:

> In how long a time will he arrive?